# Misalignment of values in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

The following code should create a dictionary in which the keys are the words of the input sentence and the values, starting with the number 1, respectively, to represent the number of words in the sentence. Does the following code work correctly for you?The values are not in order for me and I am very confused.

```
sentence =input()
list_words=sentence.split()
for i in list_words:
    d = {word: i for i, word in enumerate(list_words, 1)}
print(d)
```

Comment: Can you provide examples of what it outputs and what you expect it to output?

Comment: ```count = (1)``` I think that is wrong. It must be ```count = 1```

Comment: @bilakos No difference at all

Comment: You should consider using `enumerate` rather than managing the index yourself. You can the do this in a singe dict comprehension:  `d = {word: i+1 for i, word in enumerate(list_words)}`

Comment: @HamoonHekmat what you expected to output?

Comment: @MarkM Probably better start enumerating with 1 instead of adding 1 to every value.

Comment: @ bilakos For example, if I give the text of my question to the program, I expect the following answer :{'The': 1, 'following': 2, 'code': 3, 'should': 4, 'create': 5, 'a': 6, 'dictionary': 7, 'of': 8, 'input': 9, 'sentence': 10, 'words': 11, 'and': 12, 'give': 13, 'the': 14,

Comment: @Manuel fair point. Hamoon, that would look like `d = {word: i for i, word in enumerate(list_words, 1)}`

Comment: @HamoonHekmat I'm getting this results too: {'The': 1, 'following': 2, 'code': 3, 'should': 4, 'create': 5, 'a': 6, 'dictionary': 7, 'of': 8, 'input': 9, 'sentence': 10, 'words': 11, 'and': 12, 'give': 13, 'the': 14}

Comment: You want the ```count``` as KEY and the ```i ``` as VALUE? Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: **so what isnt working**

Comment: @bilakos no . I want the i as KEY and the count  as VALUE.

Comment: @ Mark M Your code is not working properly for me . The numbers are not in the dictionary value, respectively

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
sentence = str(input('Give your sentence: '))
list_words = sentence.split()
dict_word = {}
count=1
for i in list_words:
    dict_word[i] = count
    count += 1
print(dict_word)
```

My output with this code is this:

```
Give your sentence: The following code should create a dictionary of input sentence words and give the
```

```
{The': 1, 'following': 2, 'code': 3, 'should': 4, 'create': 5, 'a': 6, 'dictionary': 7, 'of': 8, 'input': 9, 'sentence': 10, 'words': 11, 'and': 12, 'give': 13, 'the': 14}
```

Comment: @ bilakos my output with your code is :{'The': 1, 'following': 2, 'code': 3, 'should': 4, 'create': 5, 'a': 25, 'dictionary': 7, 'of': 27, 'input': 9, 'sentence': 10, 'words': 11, 'and': 66, 'give': 13,

Comment: This is beyond my powers xD

Comment: @ bilakos I'm completely confused. Even the following code did not work for me......dict_word  = {word: i+1 for i, word in enumerate(list_words)}

Comment: From my side both ways worked perfectly. Are you sure that you are running the same code as you have posted and as I have answered? Try to restart your pc.

Comment: @ bilakos ..I am using Python 3.9 on Windows. how about you ?

Comment: I am using the same on Windows.

Comment: @bilakos Note the `'and': 66` in their result, clearly they're abusing it by having duplicate words and their full expected result (which they refuse to show) might be impossible.

Comment: @Manuel Yep true!